# ARM Template split array into more granular controls

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I haven't coded much in recent years, outside of SQL.  I have to implement a custom template to Azure but I'm not sure how to split the authorizations array into single segments to display better in the Azure portal.

I've developed the template and created the parameters file.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "mspOfferName": {
            "value": "Offer01"
        },
        "mspOfferDescription": {
            "value": "Blah Blah"
        },
        "managedByTenantId": {
            "value": "GUID"
        },
        "authorizations": {
            "value": [
                        { 
                            "principalId": "{AAD Group ID to go here}", 
                            "roleDefinitionId": "GUID",
                            "principalIdDisplayName": "Contributors",
                            "tags": ["Owners: abc, Contributors: def"]
                        }, 
                        { 
                            "principalId": "{AAD Group ID to go here}", 
                            "roleDefinitionId": "GUID",
                            "principalIdDisplayName": "Readers" 
                        },
            {
                            "principalId": "{AAD Group ID to go here}",
                            "principalIdDisplayName": "PIM_Group",
                            "roleDefinitionId": "GUID",
                            "delegatedRoleDefinitionIds": [
                                "GUID",
                                "GUID"
                            ]
                        }   
                    ]
        }
    }
}
```

It uploads into Azure without issues, but I'd like to see more controls on the portal.  Right now all I see is this:

[image]

Is there some way to see more controls; say: a textbox for principalId, a textbox for roleDefinitionId, a textbox for principalDisplayName for each group?

Comment: the view is based on your template. We cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.

When you deploy the template in the portal, just every independent parameter defined in `parameters` will have a textbox.